# Generic JSON parser to CustomObject

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing, json.net

I have a JSON content like:

```
{
 "ABCD1":[{"gopName":"JHIKJUS"},{"gopName":"LKKJHGYT"}],
 "CBFD1":[{"gopName":"HT"},{"gopName":"OP"}]
}
```

I have created one custom Class i.e.

```
public class DeskGopMapper
        {
            public List<string> GopName { get; set; }
            public string DeskName { get; set; }
        }
```

Need to know how can we write a custom parser so that it should not be tightly coupled.

Have tried something like:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"sample.txt"))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var line = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var rawObj = JObject.Parse(line);
                List<DeskGopMapper> map = new List<DeskGopMapper>();
                foreach (var obj in rawObj)
                {
                    var m = new DeskGopMapper {DeskName = obj.Key, GopName = new List<string>()};

                    foreach (var prop in obj.Value)
                    {
                         m.GopName.Add(prop["gopName"].ToString());
                    }
                    map.Add(m);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Though i am not very much convinced with way of parsing.

What is the better way to achieve Parsing the JSON response into `List<DeskGopMapper>` ?

Comment: What would you consider to be a 'better' way?  What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Hello Gareth, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it  ? When i say better i meant better way to deal with JSON having nested content representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API to simplify your code:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"sample.txt");

List<DeskGopMapper> map = JObject.Parse(json)
    .Properties()
    .Select(p => new DeskGopMapper
    {
        DeskName = p.Name,
        GopName = p.Value.Children<JObject>()
                         .Select(j => (string)j["gopName"])
                         .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0d2ZzH

Comment: Looks more simplified.Thanks